# Converting Data into pandas data frame format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have following dummy calculation in `Python` language

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

result = ### based on some calculation

print(result)
```

With this I am getting answer in below format:

```
(
    (
        'date', pywintypes.datetime(2020, 6, 15, 0, 0, tzinfo=TimeZoneInfo('GMT Standard Time', True)), pywintypes.datetime(2020, 7, 15, 0, 0, tzinfo=TimeZoneInfo('GMT Standard Time', True))
    ),
    (
        'var1', 200, 340
    ),
    (
        'var2', 1200, -340
    )
)
```

I failed to understand what is this format exactly? How can I convert this data to a `Pandas data-frame` format for further calculation?

Any pointer will be very helpful.

Comment: The code you are showing doesn't produce the results you say you are getting.  For us to help you, provide a minimal reproducible problem set containing sample input, expected output, actual output, and all relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. What you have provided falls short of this goal. See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your tuple of tuples format you could use:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(result).set_index(0).T
```

Output:

```
        date var1  var2
1 2020-06-15  200  1200
2 2020-07-15  340  -340
```

Answer (score 1):

seems like its a tuple of tuples , but if you run this :

```
print(type(result))
```

you can get a better idea

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
pd.DataFrame(list(result))
```